# forcing EDIT of access backend database

Tags: permissions, microsoft-access

here is my situation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962892/forcing-edit-of-access-backend-database

i am wondering if there is a permissions solution. perhaps i can have the network guy remove the ability for anyone to edit except for me?

do you know if there might be disastrous impact on the database itself if i go this route?

i have a bunch of users connecting to the backend of an access database, i need to edit the back end but unfortunately cannot log people out.

Comment: Have you considered just adding some logic into the front-end to log access of the database into the database when a user open/closes it?  If you know who is causing the problem you could fall back to publicly ridiculing them.

Comment: There is no server-based/permissions solution to this. You can't change the permissions on a file while it is open, and if you change the permissions to prevent your users from entering it, they won't be able to edit their data. The solutions cited in the answers on SO are your only solution. Of course, I've been doing Access apps with Jet/ACE back ends since 1996 and this has only been an issue in one application I've ever had running. In that case, I put in log-off code that shut down any running instance of the front end at midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see I responded to that question.  Why won't my response there, copied below, work for you?   Alternatively you could have a hidden form with a timer set to go every, say 60 seconds, and check a field in a table in the backend to exit users out.

[Idle Detect/Inactivity Timeout](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/idledetecttimeout.htm)